# PHP Parsing XML to Array using XmlExtractor - Bug

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I am using [XmlExtractor](https://github.com/pwarelis/XmlExtractor)  to parse an XML file into an array in PHP.

Unfortunately, there is a bug when it comes to repeated array elements.  Here's the example input Earth.xml:

```
<earth>
    <people>
        <person>
            <name id = "1">
                <first>Paul</first>
                <last>Warelis</last>
            </name>
            <name id = "2">
                <first>George</first>
                <last>Stein</last>
            </name>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <skill>Javascript</skill>
            <skill>PHP</skill>
            <skill>Beer</skill>
        </person>
    </people>
</earth>
```

There are two name elements (one with "id = 1'", the other one with "id =2 "). I would like to turn this entire XML into an array. Here's the code for that:

```
$source = new XmlExtractor("earth", $file);
      foreach ($source as $people) {
         $result = $people->export(true);
      }

      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($result);
      echo '</pre>';
```

However, in this case XmlExtractor would turn the name element with "id = 2" into a subelement of the first name element. Here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [people] => Array
        (
            [person] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [first] => Paul
                            [last] => Warelis
                            [name] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [first] => George
                                    [last] => Stein
                                )

                        )

                    [gender] => Male
                    [skill] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Javascript
                            [1] => PHP
                            [2] => Beer
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The author of XmlExtractor has confirmed to me that this is a bug. However, unfortunately the project is no longer maintained and I have not been able to fix the problem myself so far. Would anyone be able to look into this and identify the source of the problem?

The author has confirmed he would merge the solution into the package, so that others may also benefit.

Thanks!
pancid

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have two first and last names for one person? For another person, you would add another 'person' tag in your XML file, like so:

```
<earth>
    <people>
        <person>
            <name id = "1">
                <first>Paul</first>
                <last>Warelis</last>
            </name>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <skill>Javascript</skill>
            <skill>PHP</skill>
            <skill>Beer</skill>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name id = "2">
                <first>George</first>
                <last>Stein</last>
            </name>
            <gender>Male</gender>
            <skill>AngularJS</skill>
            <skill>PHP</skill>
            <skill>Beer</skill>
        </person>
    </people>
</earth>
```

Comment: Logically, you are right. However, the xml provided is just an example to illustrate the bug in the code. It doesn't matter what the name of an element is, the problem is always the same. The only way to solve this is to fix the source code of XmlExtractor on https://github.com/pwarelis/XmlExtractor/tree/master/src